# Powershell REST API Call returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a REST API Call from Powershell, but instead of JSON it seems to return html - If i do the same API Request from Python or Postman, i receive propper JSON

Here's the PS Code:

```
  $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer tokenKey" }
  Invoke-RestMethod 'https://horace.eu.tbh.eu/api/v1/hardware/?search=4C:CC:6A:7C:48:72' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```

I have the feeling that i am doing something fundamentally wrong but can't pin it down. So someone please point me into the right direction :-)

Lars

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you guys - the moment i posted the question i found the answer:

Apparently Invoke-RestMethod does not carry the Authorization header over to the redirection target.